# How do I print out contents of a Key in a dictionary in PYTHON?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following Dictionary. I am trying to print contents of a key line by line without any special character.

```
{'view': ['premium_user', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['Admin', 'normal_content']}
```

Each key has more than 1 element within. The Desired output for key "view" should look like the this:

```
premium_user
premium_content
```

I've tried this by writing the following code, where operation is the key (passed in a method) and access is the dictionary.

```
    if operation in access:
        print(access[operation])
```

But the printout is in this format.

```
['premium_user', 'premium_content']
```

How can I get the desired output from the key ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the output is a list, and you need string output, you can try to join list via \n:

```
a={'view': ['premium_user', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['Admin', 'normal_content']}
print("\n".join(a["view"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to print all the values

```
a={'view': ['premium_user', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['Admin', 'normal_content']}
for i in a.keys():
    for t in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][t])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which value you want to print:

```
dict = {'view': ['premium_user', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['Admin', 'normal_content']}

print(dict['view'][1])
```

What the print function above does is it navigates to the dictionary (in this case I named it as "dict"), then it navigates to the key specified (in this case it is "view"), then you specify which value you want it to print (in this case I chose the second value "[1]")